# Struts2 checkbox label to change with jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2, jsp-tags

I am using jquery to change the label of the checkboxes.

```
use strict';
$("#chId").click(function () {
   if (this.checked) {
         $('#divId').html("Checked");
   }
   else{
         $('#divId').html("Un-Checked");
   }

});
```

It works OK if I specify checkbox in regular html style

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chId"/> 
<div id='divId'>Checked</div>
```

There are several checkboxes and I am using different "divId" for each text to change
However, I need to specify it with the struts checkbox tag with the "label" attribute.
I know that when it's done like this, I will have label rendered on html as

```
<label for"checkbox_class">Checked</label>
```

And if if change jquery just a little to select by class "label" it will work

```
$('.label').html("Checked");
```

But, if I have multiple check boxes, all the labels would have the same class ".label" and I am not sure how to make different text by check box change not at the same time
Basically, I want to either
   1) have 5 labels to all have different classes "label1", ... "label5" or
   2) have id on each label so that ... or
   3) be able to use "for" attribute in a jquery selector?
I think #(3) is my best bet, but I don't know how to to do it.
Can anyone help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give class and id attributes to your checkboxes and use [jQuery attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get label element where `for` attribute equals checkbox id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(".checkb").click(function () {
      if(this.checked) {
        $("label[for="+this.id+"]").html("Checked");
      }else {
        $("label[for="+this.id+"]").html("Un-Checked");
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<s:checkbox cssClass="checkb" id="checkid1" name="check1" label="Un-Checked"/>
<s:checkbox cssClass="checkb" id="checkid2" name="check2" label="Un-Checked"/>
```